# Bootstrap Validator revalidate

Tags: jquery, bootstrapvalidator

I'm trying to assign a value to an input box using:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("input:text").val("Glenn Quagmire");
});
```

This works OK but Bootstrap Validator doesn't see the value change, if I enter something using keyboard BV validates the new value.
I'm using this version http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.4.5/js/bootstrapvalidator.min.js

thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm use this:

```
$("#input").val('text');
$("#input").change();
```

I guess the validator only works when the 'change' event is called, so I forced this event and it works.

Comment: Thanks! I change a little my answer, but I don't know more than that... =/